# Vb.net getting weekday name

Tags: vb.net

Today is 21.10.2012. and it is Sunday.
But my VB.NET think different:

```
Debug.Print("Weekday for the date '21.10.2012.'is " & WeekdayName(Weekday("21.10.2012.")))
Debug.Print("Weekday for the date '21/10/2012'is " & WeekdayName(Weekday("21/10/2012")))
Debug.Print("Weekday for the date '" & DateTime.Now.Date & "'is " & WeekdayName(Weekday(DateTime.Now.Date)))
```

All those 3 checks give me: 'Monday' for weekday name!
What to do to get proper weekday names?

Comment: I know this is old, but thought I'd explain why this is not working. The Weekday returns an integer representing the day of week, starting from 1=Sunday. WeekdayName functions starts the week as Monday=1. That's why it's out of sync and returning the wrong day name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the correct .NET way to get the weekday name of a given date:

```
Dim myCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
Dim dayOfWeek As DayOfWeek = myCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(Date.Today)
' dayOfWeek.ToString() would return "Sunday" but it's an enum value,
' the correct dayname can be retrieved via DateTimeFormat.
' Following returns "Sonntag" for me since i'm in germany '
Dim dayName As String = myCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(dayOfWeek)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, this works. In my question I also get local name for day so I'm wondering now in which culture 21.10.2012. is monday? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Label1.Text = Date.Today.ToString("dddd")
```

Comment: This doesn't address the asker's actual question.

Answer (score -1):

You Need 3 Steep :

1- Create Button + DateTimePicker + TextBox

In Button Code Add :

```
TextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dddd")
```

Comment: Please just answer the question. There was no UI in the question, so you shouldn't have it in the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).